# Prisma studio does not save the input

Tags: postgresql, next.js, prisma, vercel

I just try prisma and i got this problem without error message on console or prisma it self. I figure out to solve this problem for 3hrs and i haven't got any solution for this.

So my problem is when i try to save the record of my data on prisma studio at PhoneNumber field, the value that i fill just dissapear or unsaved

[This is the screenshot when i try to add some data on prisma studi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNzRU.png)

[After save the record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEf9y.png)

[schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYL3s.png)

[migration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRwdV.png)

```
     "dependencies": {
        "@prisma/client": "^5.9.1",
        "clsx": "^2.1.0",
        "next": "14.1.0",
        "react": "^18",
        "react-dom": "^18",
        "react-icons": "^5.0.1",
        "zod": "^3.22.4"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^20",
        "@types/react": "^18",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
        "eslint": "^8",
        "eslint-config-next": "14.1.0",
        "postcss": "^8",
        "prisma": "^5.9.1",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
        "typescript": "^5"
      }
```

I hope anyone have any solution for this. thanks!!